# Failed to load docker configuration: .docker/features.json: input/output error

Tags: docker, containers

This my versions:

```
Windows 10 home ed.
Ubuntu WSL2 20.04 LTS
Docker latest build
```

This happen after I do cleanup with commands below

```
docker-compose down

#remove container
docker rm -vf $(docker ps -a -q)

#remove image
docker rmi -f $(docker images -a -q)

#remove container
docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -q)
```

when I run docker-compose build, error shown:

```
Failed to load docker configuration: open /home/happyboy/.docker/features.json: input/output error
```

then I check with

```
docker -v  (success)
docker-compose --version  (fail with same error of unable to load docker configuration)
```

still same error, failed to load docker configuration...

so I end up uninstall and reinstall docker to have docker-compose work again.
after use for around 2 days, this compose error come up again...

This issue already happen twice in past few days.
It will be problematic if every time I also have to reinstall docker.

anyone got solution?

Comment: Is the file `/home/happyboy/.docker/features.json` exist in your system?

Comment: Yes, exist. Both features.json and contexts in the same directory cannot open, maybe is some file locking. 
other files like config.json, canary.json, .token_seed etc I able to right click view in notepad.

Answer (score 23):

I got the same error when trying to run any `docker-compose` command on **Ubuntu WSL2 20.04 LTS**.

I make it work by renaming  the `~/.docker` folder:

```
mv ~/.docker ~/.docker_old
```

My `docker version` is:

> Version:          20.10.7

---

Credit: [**GitHub Docker Issue Discussion**](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/3785#issuecomment-715499194)

Comment: Worked for me as well!

Comment: It worked for me using Ubuntu WSL 18.04

Answer (score 6):

I found this works in my win10 home edition.

step 1. Run > type in services.msc > select LxssManager and restart

step 2. restart docker exe

then go to ubuntu type in :
docker-compose --version

Answer (score 2):

I found out that my `~/.docker/features.json` file was empty. I solved the error by editing it to have "`{}`" (empty json object).

Answer (score 0):

Restart WSL should help.

Run in wondows console:

```
wsl --shutdown
```

Then

```
wsl
```

Seems this makes the same as [@i-need-help mentioned by restrarting LxssManager in services](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68393491/2466932).